# devise: not requiring email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I would like to NOT require email for signing in using devise. I removed email from config/initializers/devise.rb:

```
config.authentication_keys = [ :login ]
```

and added this to my user model:

```
def email_required?
  false
end
```

However, I am getting this error when I try to save the user:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: users.email may not be NULL
```

Am I suppose to change something in the migration?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It looks like you have the email field set in the database as "not NULL" or "Allow Null" to false. 
And you are getting an error directly from the database. 
Assuming that your user model is called user you need to add the fallowing migration to fix that:

```
change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true
```

Documentation:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements/change_column

Comment: As far as I can tell, more than this is required. The solution in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18017413/199712) worked for me.

Answer (score 35):

In my case, I removed the column `email` from my **users** in the database, and **Devise** started to crash. I added this:

```
# app/models/user.rb
def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end
```

and it worked properly.

Please note that removing `:validatable` would remove [password validations](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Validatable). So some references say you shoudn't remove it.

---

Tip: Add a simple comment above those lines explaining your motives. Those after you will be thankful

Comment: Yea this is very important

Answer (score 8):

Additional to removing "required" from :email column you need to remove ":validatable" from user model.

Answer (score 0):

If the issue was that the service in-question wasn't providing an email to you, this is a bit cleaner of a solution:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview#user-didnt-allow-email-permissions