# Rails Devise Token Auth authentication without using email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I want to use 'username' field instead 'email'

I used gems

```
gem 'devise'
gem 'devise_token_auth'
```

My model 'User'

```
devise :database_authenticatable,
         :trackable, :registerable, :authentication_keys => [:username]
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  has_many :projects

  def email_required?
    false
  end

  def email_changed?
    false
  end
```

I removed 'validatable'

And tried change model

```
change_column :users, :email, :string, :null => true
remove_index :users, :email
```

Also I set configuration device.rb

```
config.authentication_keys = [:username]
config.case_insensitive_keys = [:username]
config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:username]
```

But I still have an error

```
"Email can't be blank",
"Email is not an email"
```

What I made wrong? Thank You

Comment: did you try to run the migrations? See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165843/devise-not-requiring-email), it can be helpful

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution

routes.rb

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', :controllers => { :registrations => "registrations" }
```

And then make registration youself

**rails routes** have this

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                    Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /auth/sign_in(.:format)        devise_token_auth/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /auth/sign_in(.:format)        devise_token_auth/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /auth/sign_out(.:format)       devise_token_auth/sessions#destroy
cancel_user_registration GET    /auth/cancel(.:format)         registrations#cancel
   new_user_registration GET    /auth/sign_up(.:format)        registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /auth/edit(.:format)           registrations#edit
       user_registration PATCH  /auth(.:format)                registrations#update
                         PUT    /auth(.:format)                registrations#update
                         DELETE /auth(.:format)                registrations#destroy
                         POST   /auth(.:format)                registrations#create
     auth_validate_token GET    /auth/validate_token(.:format) devise_token_auth/token_validations#validate_token
```

Can use methods

```
- valid_token?
- create_new_auth_token
- build_auth_header
```

Look

https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth

[Unpermitted Parameters adding new fields to Devise in rails 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17384289/unpermitted-parameters-adding-new-fields-to-devise-in-rails-4-0)

Also you can delete email validation from devise_token_auth

Add file config/initializers/change_email_valid_devise_token_auth.rb

```
EmailValidator.class_eval do
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  end
end
```