# Devise Tumblr Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, single-sign-on, omniauth, tumblr

### There is a way for create users without email with Devise?

I'm creating a single sign-on with **Tumblr**, **Omniauth** and **Devise** When accept on Tumblr dialog, it returns:

```
NoMethodError in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#tumblr
undefined method `email' for #<User:0x00007f8835e4e110>
```

**Tumblr don't provide email** from their users on the whole hash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved!**

I used  this [devise: not requiring email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9165843/devise-not-requiring-email)

Then, removing from user model `:validatable` and this two methods:

```
def email_required?
  false
end

def email_changed?
  false
end
```